# uint256[] array formatting

Tags: etherscan, myetherwallet

I'm currently trying to enable zk-proof verification on Ethereum. The zk-proof I'm using is an array of uint256[8]. I manage to verify it locally, but if I want to submit it to the Rinkeby testnet through the Etherscan contract interface. I get a typeerror, when trying to write the values as an array.

I was wondering whether somebody knows the correct format when writing an array (uint256[8]) to a contract using MEW/Etherscan or another platform?

**Contract**

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x56804F39a898b2607ecd41A7F6a4D482DC15073f#writeContract

**Values**

deployRenter: 0.6

_ppc: 0x3864db492ea1817cd722e69210857480075a08da7d5aab3da4c60d4da1a03125

_r: 0xdf79e84fa75d57fc84d4dcdee39030f33714c4c1beeff804e26af8a1314e592e

_s: 0x781f0568991dfac047eaf9ebe83df3e24254bf1d7ccfcac49c20f187be19593b

_v: 27

Verify_deployRenterproof: ['11014804280498173996371870034282977682206158250531495349377289989445413365492','21227707827012713913025612553955593860819922575810543781723818087545239424785',   '20455701651325141130707960947541191569094470759307876535045331233510970382977','20878365366855099273541058485942850396375994988992146685194295423210057056533','4789227134106595071719519609365832853516546056916330161072411497180681132151',   '12057322530346973393171898575858898867552551582146891559350101405991713199093', '6397540020422338085233907082172467475349404015162612289997239902254115476791', '14486654477843838294702863102857924644412904839305621820045087144397542093670']

genParam: ['6000000000000000020']

Answer (score 1):

The format for a uint256[8] input on remix is as follows:

["0x1dad21c7e2e06c49150029885aa66a5b3838ecb285eac0c99992b86eec69b9f7",
"0x06d8cb9bc99d787b486478b78450871782a36b76edc198c3477e893043d99cc5",
"0x24f30366745359bf022bac5f75bcef4bff819868c4a4d5eec66e40b8c5399c7d",
"0x200f7f266e3e8ebf7ca70a884006c7d1705a36a19e1078a0fb738f8fe16b7af1",
"0x226dee3fe96cb68dfea5f4e29a136c194e7bf0a84008f7f5a3702100c28b369a",
"0x0fba3eef067319766d5a1ceb67a58548f12cd6868482d8f62b1d060cd783c3de",
"0x2deae3c6bf665d84cbf8795c458aa156b41104c74b2e69a07856bcfab3bf9434",
"0x0344b184bd9cd023d2db2f22d675126466e97a5677c90cbf37a926be2ed22486"]

There cannot be spaces and the hex format is a valid representation of uint256.

Comment: Thank you it worked! Or at least until I tried to pass 0s: ` invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value=" 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.1.1)`

Answer (score 0):

In Etherscan, it works for me when I passed the hexadecimal value without quotation. So

`_inputNumbers (uint256[6])` of `[200, 300, 500, 1500, 2500, 5000]`

will be

`[0xC8,0x12C,0x1F4,0x5DC,0x9C4,0x1388]`